# Наполнение DataGrid данными из БД

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid

Переношу программу с WinForms на WPF. Раньше дел с WPF не имел, столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами. Был фрагмент кода:

```
SQLiteCommand command =
            new SQLiteCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM table WHERE какое-то условие", connection);
        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable); dataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
```

Переношу данный код на WPF следующим образом:

```
SQLiteCommand command =
            new SQLiteCommand(
                "SELECT * FROM table WHERE какое-то условие", connection);
        SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView; //dataGrid.DataContext = dataTable.DefaultView;
```

В XAML файле для грида выставлено AutoGenerateColumns="True". Всё вроде бы работает как мне хочется, пока SQL запрос не возвращает пустой ответ. В этом случае, при попытке обратиться к заголовку какого-либо столбца dataGrid, возникает исключение, указывающее на недопустимый индекс столбца. Например: `dataGrid.Columns[0].Header = "Заголовок";`

А обращаться к нему периодически требуется. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой конкретной проблемы, можно сделать сопоставление возвращаемой в результате запроса таблицы в коллекцию объектов конкретного класса. Вот в этом [топике](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56857/81962) предлагается extension метод для упрощения подобного преобразования.

В вашем случае нужно создать класс (пусть для примера будет TableClass), который представляет модель данных из таблицы table, и после получения результатов из БД выполнить следующее:

```
List<TableClass> list = dtTable.DataTableToList<TableClass>();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
```

Метод в любом случае (кроме исключения в результате несовпадения типов) вернёт `List<TableClass>`, а не null, а значит и коллекция колонок не будет пустой и можно будет переименовать заголовки.

Но вообще, если вы переходите от полноценного байндинга в WinForms к такому же полноценному в WPF, то следует заменить List на ObservableCollection, реализующую INotifyPropertyChanged, и пытаться придерживаться шаблона MVVM.